# Web API facebook, email claim returns null

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api, registration, claims-based-identity

Code is as follows

startup auth:

```
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "xxx",
            AppSecret = "xxx",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location",
            Scope = { "email" }
        });
```

in the accountcontroler RegisterExternal class i call the following:

var info = await AuthenticationManager_GetExternalLoginInfoAsync_WithExternalBearer();

Which is this class:

```
private async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> AuthenticationManager_GetExternalLoginInfoAsync_WithExternalBearer()
    {
        ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = null;

        var result = await Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);

        if (result != null && result.Identity != null)
        {
            var idClaim = result.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (idClaim != null)
            {
                loginInfo = new ExternalLoginInfo()
                {
                    DefaultUserName = result.Identity.Name == null ? "" : result.Identity.Name.Replace(" ", ""),
                    Login = new UserLoginInfo(idClaim.Issuer, idClaim.Value),
                };

            }
        }
        return loginInfo;
    }
```

This is because the RegisterExternal class on default will use authentication type cookie. Whenever i use it it will return null, so after surfing the web I've noticed it is necessary add this code which in turn will use the bearer for authentication, this will result in a reply where the username and the identity are no longer null, thus authorized. (see picture below)

[Return object (username and login)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTwa0.png)

But, when i want to claim the email, i cannot do this. It will always return null no matter what i do.

Comment: Facebook does not have to fulfil the Email claim. Are you sure this is always the case? Can you check with other FB accounts?

Comment: I have verified that facebook is indeed asking for the email upon its request, and if i look into that request i see that facebook is sending my email. (whenever you press a button 'login with facebook' facebook pops up a screen with 'the app will receive the following'. There it does ask for my email and if i edit the data i see my email displayed, so thats working fine)

Comment: Did you ever solve this @MichaelTralala? Running into the same thing at the moment

Comment: @Braydie i did not resolve this issue. I think its better not to use the webapi build in function and download and configure the facebook api manual.

Comment: I forgot that I'd asked! I think I may have something working - will post it up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same issue and solved it by using the Facebook nuget package to get extra fields.

In my application I have implemented `FacebookAuthenticationProvider` and overridden the `Authenticated(...)` method with the following:

```
public class FacebookAuthProvider : FacebookAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task Authenticated(FacebookAuthenticatedContext context)
    {
        var accessTokenClaim = new Claim("ExternalAccessToken", context.AccessToken, "urn:facebook:access_token");
        context.Identity.AddClaim(accessTokenClaim);
        var extraClaims = GetAdditionalFacebookClaims(accessTokenClaim);
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, extraClaims.First(k => k.Key == "email").Value.ToString()));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Provider", context.Identity.AuthenticationType));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)));

        var userDetail = context.User;
        var link = userDetail.Value<string>("link") ?? string.Empty;
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("link", link));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookId", userDetail.Value<string>("id")));
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private static JsonObject GetAdditionalFacebookClaims(Claim accessToken)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken.Value);
        return fb.Get("me", new { fields = new[] { "email", "first_name", "last_name" } }) as JsonObject;
    }
}
```

My `Startup.cs` has this within `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`:

```
FacebookAuthOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
      AppId = "YOUR APP ID",
      AppSecret = "YOUR APP SECRET",
      Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Account/ExternalCallBack"), // whatever your external callback url is
      Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
};
FacebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(FacebookAuthOptions);
```

I've no idea why the email was not being populated in the first place, but this approach worked for me.